# Random wire antenna - why only one wire?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism

If my understanding of AC and the generation of electromagnetic radiation is correct, then a complete circuit encapsulating power source and resonator is required (a closed circuit). How then can a "random wire" antenna function, as it is an open circuit with infinite resistance - no current should flow when induced by EM radiation.

Comment: The key is to realize "[the missing half-side of a monopole antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopole_antenna#Radiation_pattern)" (what people refer to as "the ground", "the reference plane", "the counterpoise", or "image antenna"), is often created by the surrounding objects near the antenna wire, such as a metal plate or the actual Earth soil, which is electrically connected to the radio receiver. And in the worst case scenario when there's no object around a random wire antenna in the free space, still, the circuit ground of the radio receiver itself will become its missing half.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. The electrons are displaced by the EM radiation, much as a potential difference in a closed circuit would

Answer (score -2):

The path is through electromagnetic radiation.  You don't need wired connections to transfer electromagnetic energy.  Have you done the obvious, and search "How do antennas work" on YouTube??  There's a bunch of good videos

Comment: Yes, all just show a wire going to an antenna, with no mention of the number of cores. My prior assumption was that electromagnetic energy won't be induced without a complete circuit, otherwise it's just like an open switch.

Comment: @Chorlton2080  Think it heuristically: consider a dipole antenna, you can make one by putting two metal plates/wires next to each other, a radio receiver is connected between them. There's no closed loop. It's an open DC circuit. However, EM wave in free space can induce a potential difference between two plates. By measuring it, you can receive signals. If you agree a dipole antenna can work, then, if you replace one plate with a random wire, replace another plate with the circuit ground in the radio receiver, such as a metal wire going to the negative battery electrode, it should still work.

Comment: This helps my understanding. Thank you.